# Scraping a table for links, getting data from each link, and doing the same for many pages (pagination)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a list of `5000` best movies, spanning `50` pages. The website is

```
http://5000best.com/movies/
```

I want to extract the names of the 5000 movies, then click on each movie name link. Each link will redirect me to the `IMDb` page. Then, I want the `director's` name to be extracted. 
This will give me a table with 5000 rows, with the columns being the name of the movie and the director.
This data will be exported to csv or to xlsx.

I have the following for extracting text so far:

```
import requests
start_url = 'http://5000best.com/movies/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

Comment: So where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed, and how to incorporate pagination

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, this is a wee bit broad. Can you scrape one page of links and get the director names? After you've successfully done that, then it's a matter of finding the link to the next page and requesting that in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the main logic for pagination. Hope you get along from there. To capture all pages just loop until the next page doesn't exist.

```
import requests
import bs4

i = 1
while 1:
    url = f'http://5000best.com/movies/{i}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    # looking at the HTML we can find the main table
    table = soup.find('table', id="ttable")

    # analyse the HTML and process the table here

    # if the table is empty, we are beyond the last page
    if len(table.find_all('tr')) == 0:
        break
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is getting the pagination link
This is how the link works

```
http://5000best.com/?m.c&xml=1&ta=13&p=1&s=&sortby=0&y0=&y1=&ise=&h=01000000000000000
```

There are 2 parameters that change with each page the `p` and `h` (Although the links seem to work irrespective of the h parameter)

so the link for page 2 will look like this:

```
http://5000best.com/?m.c&xml=1&ta=13&p=2&s=&sortby=0&y0=&y1=&ise=&h=02000000000000000
```

and 50 be like:

```
http://5000best.com/?m.c&xml=1&ta=13&p=50&s=&sortby=0&y0=&y1=&ise=&h=05000000000000000
```

Hope you can handle the rest